# How to continue normal execution after exception in Common Lisp?

Tags: error-handling, common-lisp, sbcl, condition-system

I want to catch `unbound-variable` exceptions and avoid them, creating some variables on-the-fly without execution breaks.
I'm trying to use `handler-bind` with `invoke-restart` in the following code:

```
(defmacro my-progn (&rest rest)
  `(handler-bind
    ((unbound-variable
      (lambda (x)
        (progn
          ;(format t "UNBOUND VAR: ~a~%"
          ;  (symbol-name (cell-error-name x)))
          (invoke-restart 'just-continue)))))
    (progn ,@(mapcar (lambda (x)
                      `(restart-case ,x (just-continue () "XXXX"))) rest))))

(my-progn
  (print "AAA")
  (print xxxx) ;; xxxx is unbound
  (print "BBB"))
```

The result is:

```
"AAA"
"BBB"
```

But I want to contiunue the execution of second `print`, just replacing unbound variable xxxx to string "XXXX":

```
"AAA"
"XXXX"
"BBB"
```

Of course, I can wrap *any* symbol in the syntax tree with `handler-bind`, but I'm afraid this will produce a huge overhead.

Is there a way just to catch `unbound-variable` exceptions and continue code execution with the dynamically generated values instead of missing variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the appropriate [standard restart](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/r_use_va.htm) `use-value`.

```
(handler-bind
    ((unbound-variable
      (lambda (c)
        (declare (ignore c))
        (use-value "XXXX"))))
  (print "AAA")
  (print xxxx)
  (print "BBB"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have already found a solution with (defvar) and (contiune), but your variant is much better!